# open docx file from onedrive for business with some webapp but not word online

Tags: onedrive, office365api, filehandler

this is not a question but kind of a request.
I have tried to find right place to post
(asked to msdn forum, partnership support, ...)
but failed.
why microsoft gives me this difficulty?
can't place a total official support page?

anyway, this is not the subject of this post.
someone suggested me to post here.
(https : // social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11fd7f37-bec6-4201-b5ce-085f24446362/forum-for-office-365-filehandler-addin?forum=whatforum)

I asked this question before, and I know it is impossible at current time.
(http : // stackoverflow.com/questions/36172056/can-i-make-office-365-file-handler-for-existing-file-format-docx-xlsx-pptx)
but I need that feature.  (open docx file with custom file handler)
so I want to request microsoft to support this feature.
and want to have clear answer thought it will be "never available."

if replacing associated webapp(office online) is unacceptable,
way to add new context menu item is enough, I think.
(like google drive does - https : // developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible with custom action of file handler 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to file handler to support the Office document, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). And you can find the document/resource/code sample about Office development from the [Office Dev Center](http://dev.office.com/).